# Can I create more than 1 fork in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I forked a project a while back and made some changes.  Some of these changes were pulled back into  the original project, but some weren't.

Other people have forked my fork as they find the changes that weren't pulled into the original useful.

I now want to fork the original project again as I have some more changes that I'd like to contribute.

I don't want to delete my original fork as it has some useful stuff, but I do want to fork again for my latest changes.

Can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new branch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772684/how-can-i-fork-my-own-github-repository seems related

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An indirect answer to your question: I've found it very useful, when cloning git projects, to leave the master alone and do all my work on a branch. That way, you can always base changes on the current "official" master.

Comment: Seconded.  Use the hell out of branches.  You can make a new branch to replace your current master, then reset master back to the upstream's master.  Make a new branch for the new thing you're working on, and push forward on that branch.